# Simple count using jQuery

Tags: jquery, counter

I have a set of questions and want to display a simple progress counter above them.
The code below works fine but I was wondering if somebody could advise on refactoring as theres got to be a better way of achieving this.

```
    var totalCount = $('#questions li').length,
        count = 1;
    $('.progress').html("Question " + count + " of " + totalCount);                 

    // Increment by 1 on each click
    $('.btn-next').click(function(){                        
        count ++ ;

        // remove current count
        $('.progress').empty();

        // drop in new count
        $('.progress').html("Question " + count + " of " + totalCount); 
    });

    // Decrease by 1 on each click
    $('.btn-prev').click(function(){
        count -- ;

        // remove current count
        $('.progress').empty();

        // drop in new count
        $('.progress').html("Question " + count + " of " + totalCount);
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can DRY that code up quite a lot. Try this:

```
var totalCount = $('#questions li').length + 1, // add 1 as .length is 0 based
    count = 1;

$('.btn-next, .btn-prev').click(function(){                        
    count = $(this).hasClass('btn-next') ? count - 1 : count + 1;
    $('.progress').html("Question " + count + " of " + totalCount) 
});
```

Note that you don't need the `empty()` as you're replacing the `html()` anyway.

Comment: Hi Rory
When I run your script this is the output

<div class="progress">Question NaN of 17</div>

Any idea what NaN is?

Comment: `NaN` means the result is not a number - usually from trying to perform a math operation on a string and an integer. Can you put your code into a http://jsfiddle.net so I can see what's happening?

Comment: @bobby_bob sorry that was my mistake - you don't need the `var` keyword on the count variable within the click handler: http://jsfiddle.net/k4Ptg/5/ I'll update my answer

Comment: @ Rory . . Spot on! fairly new to jQuery but when you receive help like this it makes the learning process that little bit easier. Thank you